# Correct PHP code to remove decimals from MAGENTO attribute

Tags: php, magento

I need to edit the following line of code to display a number WITHOUT the decimals. Not rounded up or down, just need to display a natural number. The "number" is an attribute from the database.
Here is the code:

`<?php echo $this->__('Wir haben noch ') ?> <?=Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?><?php echo $this->__(' auf Lager.') ?>`

and here is an example of what it displays now. (Sorry I couldn't post an image) http://weinwerk-klimascout.de/weinkeller/flaschenhalter-spirale.html

Instead of *Wir haben 10.0000 auf Lager*, I need "*Wir haben noch 10 auf Lager.*"

Thanks in advance !!!
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$number = '123.45';

echo intval($number);
```

so:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Wir haben noch ') ?> <?= intval(Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()); ?><?php echo $this->__(' auf Lager.') ?>
```